# change data with route param id and Pinia storage in vue js 3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

dear friends I wrote a route param id by vue js and Laravel, and now I have a problem with reactivity.
when I go to the route I can see route param id, of course, I use Pinia storage for extraction data. but in route at first, I can see data but with change route Although the param id changed but data doesn't change!

Menu link:

```
        <li v-for="cat in cats">
            <router-link :to="{name: 'Posts', params: { title: titleFormated(cat.text)  }}">{{ cat.text.toUpperCase() }}</router-link>
        </li>
```

component:

```
<template>
    {{ title }}
<br>
    {{ storeData }}
</template>
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import {useCatsStore} from "@/stores/Cats";
import {useRoute} from "vue-router/dist/vue-router";
import {computed} from "vue";


const route = useRoute();
const title = computed(() => route.params.title );
const { storeData } = storeToRefs(useCatsStore());

const { fetchItemById } = useCatsStore();

fetchItemById();

</script>
```

cats storage:

```
   state: () => {
        return {
            storeData: [],
        }
    },
actions : {
        async fetchItemById() {
            const route = useRoute();
            this.title=route.params.title;
            const response = await axios.get('/getCatById/'  + this.title + '/edit' );
            this.storeData= response.data.data;
        },
}
```

I did try with the ref and reactive data with computed but still doesn't work.

Comment: you have no code in your store to react on the route change thus no reactivity

Comment: please, can you explain more?

Comment: Don't use useRoute inside a store, it has chances to not work. In your case it's more likely that you need to watch on route change in some top-level comp, probably App.

Comment: before, I did try without useRoute and I sent param id by function, but didn't work!